# How to choose job name from Jenkinsfile when creating the pipeline from BlueOcean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

When creating a job/pipeline from BlueOcean interface the pipeline name is set to repo-name. I have a requirement to change this default behavior. We need a specific pattern in these Jenkins job name (something like a team name prefix for each pipeline name and this prefix is missing in the repo name).

I am using declarative pipeline V2. I did a search here - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options but seems no option to do so.

I am looking at any available option to be able to use my own defined name and not the repo-name by default. I found when you create a pipeline in jenkins BlueOcean and if a job already exist with the same repo name, it does allow me to override "display name". so is there a way to put job "display Name" in BlueOcean other than default.

Thanks in advance :)

Please let me know if any information is required.

Answer (score 0):

seems no option available. jenkins BlueOcean is designed to be simple. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61705